# Need advice on knocking whole party unconscious in dnd 5e

Tags: dnd-5e, lost-mine-of-phandelver

So I'm a new DM running the Lost Mine of Phandelver for the first time, and the party somehow all got knocked unconscious by the ruffians in the Tresandor Manor. They entered the manor through the tunnel that Carp found which leads to area 8. The whole party was level 2. After the battle with the nothic, they suffered some damage and pressed on to  to area 10, where they somehow kept missing their attacks and kept taking damage from the drunk ruffians in there. I'm not sure what to do with the characters at this point to continue the story. Do I just say they got captured or something? Can someone give me ideas?

Comment: Related: [Total Party Kill - What do I do as a GM?](/questions/933)

Comment: Hi Sumi, I'm not exactly sure what you are asking here. Generic requests for advice are off-topic here. Though you could try in [chat] if you need some advice. It seems like you had a TPK (total party kill) and you're not sure what to do now? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @linksassin there wasn't a TPK since all the characters are (presumably) alive. OP just doesn't know what exactly happened with them while they were unconscious.

Comment: @enkryptor you are correct. I don't really know what to do with the unconscious characters so i wanted some ideas.

Comment: Ok ill fix that. And yes its affecting the whole party so idk what to do now

Comment: A suggested edit *removed* details from the question, so I rolled it back, since removing details from a question lacking details is generally not the move.